# Django Rest Framework Example

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404

I am having problems with the example in [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/).

When I try going to the default route "/", I keep getting a 404.  The way the documentation example reads, I should be able to get a User list?

Here is the urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

# Serializers define the API representation.
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff')

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

I have the `rest_framework` added to my application, too.  I can see the various User related routes when I look at the `router` object via the `manage.py` shell, but I keep getting the 404.

I am implementing this in an existing new project, but I have yet to actually put anything in the project so I don't think the issue is there.  My current set up is Nginx proxy -> Gunicorn -> Django. The \admin site works so it looks like other things are routed fine.  Any advice would be great to help me along.

Edit: Image of the debug screen I am receiving.  URL is masked out, but this is going to just the main site `server/`.
[image]

Comment: There aren't any views that handle `/`. You should definitely change `r'^/'` to `r'^'` as Linovia suggested, then go to `server/users/`. If that doesn't work, update your question to show that code and the error you get for that URL.

Comment: **As stated in the comments to @Linovia's answer.. this has already been done.. I am not going to show every variant of code that I have tried in the major example as that would be counter productive **

Comment: I'm not asking you to show every variant of code, just one that isn't known to be incorrect.

Comment: Does it work with the development server ?

Comment: Yeah, that was what I just tried and noticed it wasn't updating via the gunicorn->nginx setup.  It is a new stack and I was unaware of the need to reload services when there are changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add a / to the router's url ?
Your code:

```
url(r'^/', include(router.urls)),
```

The example's code:

```
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

Comment: I have tried both ways, tried `/users`, `/users.`, `/users/1`, etc.  Whenever I look at the debug page, it only shows the `/admin` route and `/api-auth/` routes.  I would _assume_ that the `router.urls` would add additional routes, but I don't know DRF well enough.

Comment: remove the / from the urls.py as shown and head to `http://yoursite/` and you should get links to the appropriate url.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that before along with the other routes specified in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this solved.  It relates to [Restarting Gunicorn/Nginx when changes are made to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031855/restarting-gunicorn-nginx-when-changes-are-made-to-files).

Starting with a project already up and running then adding DRF didn't update the gunicorn/nginx parts so even if the route was correct, it wouldn't update to the outside world.

So, this is one way the correct URLs can be in `urls.py` but not reflect to the outside world.