# Autoreload flask on file save using heroku local

Tags: python, heroku, flask, heroku-toolbelt

Using [Flask Debug Mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode), the local dev server will restart on file save if you set the `debug` flag:

```
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

If you are running a Flask application with [Heroku Local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local), how do you achieve this same behavior?

Comment: What WSGI server are you using?

Comment: @dirn i am using gunicorn

Comment: While gunicorn has a [`--reload`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773763/gunicorn-autoreload-on-source-change) option, you don't really want it to run in production.