# Flask auto-detect changes to routes [in-production]

Tags: python, nginx, flask, routes, gunicorn

Does `flask` auto-detect changes to `routes`?

For example, if i have a route like:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Show homepage"
```

If this is properly working, will a new `route` like automatically be accessible at `<my-server-ip>/blog` when i add this route below ?

```
 @app.route('/')
    def myblog():
        return "Show myblog"
```

Full file:

```
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return "Show homepage"
    @app.route('/')
    def myblog():
        return "Show myblog"
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Note: `home()` is already accessible

Comment: You need `route('/blog')`

Comment: Is this auto-detected? or do I need to reload a config or something? if so, how? Im using gunicorn/nginx

Comment: if you work in debug mode then server should reload files automatically. see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode

Comment: I should have mentioned, and i will add to the question, this is a prod env

Comment: in prod dev you have to restart gunicorn - kill it and run again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773763/gunicorn-autoreload-on-source-change

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you so much! Please add as answer, so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In prod dev you have to restart gunicorn - kill it and run again.

See other options: [gunicorn autoreload on source change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773763/gunicorn-autoreload-on-source-change)

Comment: This is great, thank you. Additionally, wanted to add, if you're using supervisor to control your application, just simply run: sudo supervisorctl restart <your-project-here>