# Python Flask API : The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python, api, flask, virtual-environment

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
tasks = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "title":"You buy groceries",
        "description":"Milk, Cheeses, Pizza",
        "done":False,
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "title":"Learn Python",
        "description":"The most important language in the world",
        "done":False,
    },
]

@app.route('/add-data', methods = ['POST'])

def add_data():
    if not request.json:
        return jsonify({
            "status":"error",
            "message":"Please provide the data"
        },400)
    task = {        
        "id":tasks[-1][id]+1,
        "title":request.json["title"],
        "description":request.json.get("description",""),
        "done":False,
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    return jsonify({
        "status":"success",
        "message":"Task added successfully!"
    })

@app.route("/get-data")

def get_task():
    return jsonify({
        "data":tasks
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am just a beginner in this api creating with python and I was trying to create an api to get the data and to post data.

But when I run the code, it gives me the error :

[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtiVG.png)

Let me know if there is some error in the code or problem of the virtual environment. Would be very much grateful if the solution is also given.

Comment: can you show the url you have added ? also remove the gap between url declaration and function definiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-data"

- it pretty much serves your data.
  [image]

you do not have an auto route to the get-method yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this actually worked! And also, please tell me how to do that auto route to get-method.

Comment: A) On a basic page you can leave the "/get-data" a part away the webserver knows how to check the type of html request, as long as there' only one of each type... or: 
b) u can use redirection from the base url to the initial one (via html),
c) there are acutally more smarter ways to accomplish this result.
(I'm not a pro yet but stack overflow will have a good answer for that, too :)

Comment: Actually auto route does sth. 
different than I thought, but it might be useful to understand this and the use of decorators anyway...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015763/flask-auto-detect-changes-to-routes-in-production