# Git post-recieve hook to run virtualenv, Django & various python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, django, git

I've been successfully using Git `post-receive hook` for a while to push files from local to server using the following in my `post-receive` file:

```
#!/bin/sh  

git --work-tree=/home/myuser/myproject/app --git-dir=/home/myuser/myproject/myproject.git checkout -f
```

Now I want to also start virtual env, run Django manage.py and various python scripts after files are pushed to server using `post-receive`.

Based on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773763/gunicorn-autoreload-on-source-change) I have added following to my original `post-receive` file:

```
#!/bin/sh  

git --work-tree=/home/myuser/myproject/app --git-dir=/home/myuser/myproject/myproject.git checkout -f 
source /home/myuser/venv/bin/activate
python /home/myuser/myproject/manage.py makemigrations
python /home/myuser/myproject/manage.py migrate
python /home/myuser/myproject/app/python_script1.py
python /home/myuser/myproject/app/python_script1.py
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

But it appears that the virtual env is not being started giving me error:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: 4: hooks/post-receive: source: not found
```

Also, the remaining errors appear related to virtual env not starting. `manage.py` doesn't execute with following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
remote:   File "/home/myuser/myproject/manage.py", line 16
remote:     ) from exc
```

The python scripts appear to run but because  virtual env is not starting they are not finding modules.

The paths, file names, etc are all correct. Edit to add: Django, python scripts & virtual env run independently successfull, user has sudo no password permissions eg `user ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart gunicorn`

Edit to add: remote server is Ubuntu 18

Does anything look obviously wrong or missing with my code for this?

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be quite simple. I just had to change the shebang.

from: `#!/bin/sh`

to: `#!/bin/bash`