# How to change a container's source code and generate a new image from it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have deployed this using Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: voting-app-deploy
  labels:
    name: voting-app-deploy
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: voting-app-pod
      app: demo-voting-app
    
  template:
    metadata:
      name: voting-app-pod
      labels:
        name: voting-app-pod
        app: demo-voting-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: voting-app
          image: kodekloud/examplevotingapp_vote:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

With this Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: voting-service
  labels:
    name: voting-service
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30004
  selector:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
```

After checking if the Pods are running, I get a shell to the running container where I can see the source code and make changes using vi:

```
kubectl exec -it podsname -- sh
```

The problem is whenever I destroy the deployment and bring it back I lose all my changes in the source code.

This is the application's Dockerfile, which I got from within the running container:

```
# Using official python runtime base image
FROM python:2.7-alpine

# Set the application directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install our requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy our code from the current folder to /app inside the container
ADD . /app

# Make port 80 available for links and/or publish
EXPOSE 80

# Define our command to be run when launching the container
CMD ["gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:80", "--log-file", "-", "--access-logfile", "-", "--workers", "4", "--keep-alive", "0"]
```

So, how can I get this source code and generate a new image?

Comment: What language\framework is running in the container? Are you using docker or podman (just making sure, am aware of the tag)?

Comment: I'm using Docker. I'll update my question with the Dockerfile(not sure if it helps).

Comment: Can you check the original application out from source control; edit its code in a development environment, without involving a container system; run its unit tests; then `docker build` a new image and deploy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem that's not common, I guess. I have to clarify that i'm not working on production environment. I just want to "steal" the source code from an image, since I don't have access to the repository.

Here is what I did:

1 . Created a folder and subfolder to organize the code.
2. Got a shell inside the pod's container:

```
docker exec -it containername sh
```

or

```
kubectl exec -it podsname -- sh
```

3. From the shell, edited what I wanted to edit in the source code.
4. Copied the content of the app folder IN THE CONTAINER to my local subfolder(called 'dados'):

```
cp -R /app /dados/
```

3. Created a Dockerfile in the folder that's based on the image I want to edit, then run a command to remove the /app folder, and finally, a command to copy the contents of my local folder to the new image I was going to build.

```
FROM kodekloud/examplevotingapp_vote:v1
RUN rm -rf /app/*.*
COPY ./dados/app /app
```

4. Created a new repository on DockerHub called 'myusername/my-voting-app' to receive my new image.
5. Built the new image:

```
docker build -t myusername/my-voting-app .
```

6. Tagged the image with my repo's name:

```
docker tag kaiohenricunha/my-voting-app kaiohenricunha/my-voting-app
```

7. Sent to dockerhub:

```
docker push kaiohenricunha/my-voting-app
```

8. Now on Kubernetes, changed my pod's container image to the new image I had built and deployed them.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick and dirty**

If you change your code often and this isn't a production environment you can use the `--reload` that's according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24893069/5459640) thread is available since gunicorn 19.0. this option makes the server reload your code changes into new workers.

Then when you want to save your new image you can use `docker commit` to "commit" or save your changes to a new image like so:

```
docker commit running_container_name_or_id imagerepo/image-name:tag
```

Though this isn't that recommended in the long run just for small fixes and checks.

**Long term preferred usage**
If you want a long term method method either develop locally with a mounted bind-mount (map a folder from the host machine to the docker container) and build a final image for kubernetes, or you could mount your source code using a config map like in this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: file-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  config.conf: |
    [mysqld]
    binlog-format=mixed
```

Pod (usage in deployment is the same):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: 
spec:
  containers:
    - name: container-name
      image: image-name
      volumeMounts:
      - name: my-file-volume
        mountPath: /path/in/container/config.conf
        subPath: config.conf
  volumes:
    - name: my-file-volume
      configMap:
        name: file-configmap
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use volumes.

Volumes will allow you to map the `src` code folder in the container to a path outside of your container and it will not be destroyed during restart since it will be store outside of your container.

You can see a working sample with explanation here:
https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/09-StatefulSet

[image]

---

#### `emptyDir`

`emptyDir` is the default volume and it's being deleted when the pod is deleted, but I'm using it here to show you a sample on how to use volumes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you container(kubectl exec), use `ps | grep gunicorn` find the process of your application. Killed it then start it again.